# Label points on a Plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, labeling

I need to label the blue coloured points in the following graph I have plotted in the same plot. IN[219]
Specifically, I intend to label those points with their (x,y) values.

View my .nb file on wolfram cloud ->
https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/ramithuh/Published/ppg.nb

thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: it is better to post plain text code so someone can copy it.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
ListLinePlot[Callout[#, #] & /@ data, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

or

```
ListLinePlot[Labeled /@ data, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```